# WooCommerce Annoying Description

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I'm using wordpress with woocommerce.

I have a problem where I'm trying to figure out how to remove the Short Description or excerpt from the homepage/shop page. I still want it on when people go to the actual product but I can't figure it out.

site is    **cheap vapor therapy dot com**.  I don't want to post domain since I don't want the domain crawled from the search engines so please don't edit it.

Update -

This is to remove product title -

```
.product_item .product_details h5 
{
    display:none;
}
```

Now what would be to remove excerpt or summary on homepage?  My theme comes with custom CSS add on so a CSS code can take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the wocommerce files.
Please have a look at [this documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) to see how the overrides are done in woocommerce.

[Short decription](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.1.0/templates/single-product/short-description.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your theme is using `body_class()` in the `header.php` file, if not add it:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Then inspect the HTML code; you'll be able to fine tune almost every page individually.